# Detect when a new e-mail has been created (WithEvents)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, vb6

I am trying to call a procedure stored in Outlooks' 'ThisOutlookSession', from an Excel workbook. Unfortunately the Newer Outlook 2010 app does not have compatibility with the `application.run *SubName*` between MS office products.

It is not an option to complete an Excel script that sends the email on Outlooks behalf due to security messages on '.send' which requires a manned station. (& unable to change security settings from company policy)

Current workflow...

-User sends me an e-mail with 'command' in subject & attachments

-Event listener finds and successfully runs an Excel routine on attachments with the below headers for listening in Outlook

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
&
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
```

-Once processed in Excel, I am trying to get this data automatically returned to sender. (This is where the problem is)

I am using late binding in Excel to create and ready the return e-mail. It is one step before '.send'. I would ideally like to avoid a SendKeys statements because it is not fully reliable if working on other workbooks at the same time.

In Excel...

```
Sub test()
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

aEmail.To = "My email address"
aEmail.Subject = "Testing"
aEmail.Body = "Testing"
aEmail.display

End Sub
```

I have been endlessly trying to get Outlook to recognise Excel creating this  new email with events listed in the MSDN pages. I think something like the below code is what is needed to identify a new mailitem, but no success using most of the preset declarations under the Outlook.mailItem.

```
Private WithEvents NewItem As Outlook.mailItem
```

Please let me know if you have solution or an alternative idea for me to pursue

Comment: If downvoted, please tell me why so I can improve my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, if anyone needs this in the future. It bypasses security warnings and does not rely on send-keys.

Excel prepares an email and displays it - when prepared, the 'On event' from Outlook recognises the 'to' address when the mailitem is loaded, and can then take over from there:  finishing with a .send statement.

Note, more parameters will need to be added such as a specific code in the item.subject to ensure that its the correct e-mail that's being sent.

In Excel:

```
Sub test()
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

aEmail.To = "abs@123.com"
aEmail.Subject = "Testing"
aEmail.Body = "testing"
aEmail.Display

End Sub
```

In Outlook:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.mailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If (TypeOf Item Is mailItem) Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)

If myItem.To = "abs@123.com" Then
    MsgBox "Detected"
    myItem.Send
End If

End Sub
```